# How to add ApplicationInsights to Dependency Injection in .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: azure-application-insights

Our ASP.NET 4.8 Framework application uses Application Insights, which was configured per instructions in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net). The app uses Dependency Injection via Autofac.

We need to inject TelemetryClient into one of our service, so we can manually do some logging. In .NET core this is accompilshed by calling

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry
```

and then injecting TelemetryClient. Unfortunately, there is no AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry in the .NET Framework version of Application Insights.

Please note, we do not want to new a client via

```
new TelemetryClient()
```

because it leads to a "deprecated" warning.

In .NET Framework, is there the proper way to add Application Insights TelemetryClient to Dependency Injection?

Thank you

Comment: Do these work for ASP.NET 4.8? [new TelemetryClient(); now deprecated, initialize with configuration](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/40482) and [Configuring telemetry collection from code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/console#configuring-telemetry-collection-from-code)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to create Telemetry Client in .NET Framework Application.

[image]

- As per @[cijothomas](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1972#issuecomment-783743362), `TelemetryClient` is still in use.
- To add Application Insights TelemetryClient to Dependency Injection in .NET Framework Application, we need to install `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector` Nuget Package

`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector` is used to collect the dependency telemetry.

[image]

References taken from Doc [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#net-corenet-framework-console-application) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#automatically-tracked-dependencies)